# Parsing a JSON to convert some parameters into HEX/String

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, parsing, hex

I have the following problem, I'm new in Dart, and I'm using a Future to construct a list view from a JSON response of an API, once I do this request, I receive the following response:

REQUEST:

```
Future<List<Job>> _fetchJobs() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('http://10.10.10.254/httpapi.asp?command=wlanGetApListEx'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body)['aplist'] as List;
     print(jsonResponse);
      return jsonResponse.map((job) => new Job.fromJson(job)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load jobs from API');
    }
  }
```

```
   [
   {
      "ssid":444A446F626C65615F322E34,
      "bssid":"80":"3f":"5d":"ed":"cd":f9,
      "rssi":42,
      "channel":8,
      "auth":WPA2PSK,
      "encry":"AES",
      "extch":0
   },
   {
      "ssid":426172696369632D322E3447,
      "bssid":"b0":"76":"1b":"f4":"55":80,
      "rssi":18,
      "channel":1,
      "auth":WPA2PSK,
      "encry":"AES",
      "extch":0
   },
   {
      "ssid":46616D696C69615F65737061727A61,
      "bssid":"60":"32":"b1":"71":"ce":46,
      "rssi":0,
      "channel":5,
      "auth":WPA2PSK,
      "encry":"AES",
      "extch":0
   },
   {
      "ssid":43617361204C756369616E61,
      "bssid":"20":"ab":"48":"86":"17":58,
      "rssi":0,
      "channel":11,
      "auth":WPA2PSK,
      "encry":"AES",
      "extch":0
   }
]
```

As you can see, the SSID values are in HEX and I need it in UTF-16 or UTF-8

I was trying to implement the hex package, but I can not find how to implement it on a JSON array like this.

Comment: Hi, can you share the code of `Job`?

Comment: `class Job {
  final String ssid;
  final String auth;
  final String encry;

  Job({required this.ssid, required this.auth,required this.encry});

  factory Job.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Job(
      ssid: json['ssid'],
      auth: json['auth'],
      encry: json['encry'],
    );
  }
}`

Comment: You want to turn `444A446F626C65615F322E34` into `"444A446F626C65615F322E34"`?

Comment: I posted my answer

Comment: No, I want to convert 444A446F626C65615F322E34 to the actual ASCII value.I was exploring this solution https://pub.dev/packages/hex but I'm having trouble to implement it on this list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

class Job {
  Job({required this.ssid, required this.auth, required this.encry});

  final String ssid;
  final String auth;
  final String encry;

  factory Job.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Job(
      ssid: utf8.decode(hex.decode(json['ssid'])),
      auth: json['auth'],
      encry: json['encry'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'ssid': ssid,
      'auth': auth,
      'encry': encry,
    };
  }
}
```

---

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonResponse = (json.decode(response.body)['aplist'] as List).map((e) => Job.fromJson(e)).map((e) => e.toMap()).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The hex codex is in the `convert` package (not to be confused with the dart built in convert library).

If you need to convert the string you have to its ascii/utf8 form use both convert libraries like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

void main() {
  final h = '444A446F626C65615F322E34';
  final u = utf8.decode(hex.decode(h));
  print(u); // prints DJDoblea_2.4
}
```

The more troubling issue seems to be that the data excerpt you provide is not valid JSON, so you cannot, of course, decode it with `json.decode`.